# App Tracking Transparency popup do not appear

Tags: swift, admob, google-ads-api, privacy

I am trying to implement App Tracking Transparency in my app. I tried to do this on first ViewControllor, but it crashes the app after uploading to the test flight.

After this, I found a lot of info that this should be done in appDelegate I did this way. Of course, I have set NSUserTrackingUsageDescription in Info.plist

I tried to figure it out with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418845/app-tracking-transparency-dialog-does-not-appear-on-ios).

In the debugger, I always see "Not Determined". Could anyone please help with this?

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        requestTrackingPermission()
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        return true
    }
```

The function

```
func requestTrackingPermission() {
      if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        // ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in

          switch status {
          case .authorized:
            // Tracking authorization dialog was shown
            // and we are authorized
            print("Authorized")
             
            // Now that we are authorized we can get the IDFA
            print(ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier)
              
          case .denied:
            // Tracking authorization dialog was
            // shown and permission is denied
            print("Denied")

          case .notDetermined:
            // Tracking authorization dialog has not been shown
            print("Not Determined")
          case .restricted:
            print("Restricted")
          @unknown default:
            print("Unknown")
          }
        }
      )}
    }
```

Comment: You should request permission in a ViewControllers not the app delegate.

Comment: I tried this a few times, but if there is no button or smth like it, it just doesn't work. Could you give an example of how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found how to do this.

Add in your first ViewController

```
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport
import UserNotifications
```

Add in viewDidLoad

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
  if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { (status) in
      print("IDFA STATUS: \(status.rawValue)")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks. so much!

Answer (score -1):

Nah forget all that. It took me forever to find. But you don't need to trick it by having a delay. You just need to show xcode the app is active. Just copy and paste this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in self.requestIDFA() }
 
        return true
        
    }
    
    func requestIDFA() {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { _ in }
```