# Problem with the apple AppTrackingTransparency in expo

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am try upload my app in the apple store but i am get some erros like:

**Your app uses the AppTrackingTransparency framework, but we are still unable to locate the App Tracking Transparency permission request when reviewed on iOS 15.3.1.**

I am using the expo-tracking-transparency

but when I test in the simulator it works but when I try to test in testFlight the pop up does not appear

how i am using in the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    hideLoad();
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        // Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
      }
    })();
 ...
},[]);
```

i put this code in the index.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After finding this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69420484/14757245), where Apple's documentation says that it should be placed in the applicationDidBecomeActive, it seems like the issue is that the app isn't active.

My fix was to add a timeout around the request to wait until the application is loaded:

```
setTimeout(async () => {
  const { granted } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
}, 500);
```

Another option is to add an event listener and see when the application is active through [Expo App State](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/appstate/) and call it then.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I did what you said and now it's working

Comment: No worries, glad to hear it worked!

Comment: You saved a lot of time! Thank you, very much.

Comment: this was hard to debug, thank you, this works