# App Tracking Transparency Dialog does not appear on iOS Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am try upload my app in the apple store but i am get some erros like:

Your app uses the AppTrackingTransparency framework, but we are still unable to locate the App Tracking Transparency permission request when reviewed on iOS 15.3.1.

I am using the expo-tracking-transparency

but when I test in the simulator it works but when I try to test in testFlight the pop up does not appear

how i am using in the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
(async () => {
  const { status } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
  if (status === 'granted') {
    console.log('Yay! I have user permission to track data');
  }
})(); }, []);
```

put this code in the app.js

Comment: Hey did you solve this?
I am getting same, dialog does not appear, 
if you solved please post the answer

Comment: @chiragprajapati I think this may be helpful - it seems the request must only be triggered when the app is in the active state: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71364832/1384679

Comment: none of the solutions on SO have fixed this problem for me. Only on TestFlight am I having this issue.