# App Tracking Transparency Dialog does not appear on iOS 16.1

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, ios16, apptrackingtransparency

Apple reviewer has just rejected my app since ATT request doesn't appear: "We're looking forward to completing our review, but we need more information to continue. Your app uses the AppTrackingTransparency framework, but we are unable to locate the App Tracking Transparency permission request when reviewed on iOS 16.1"

My current code for the ATT request is as shown below:

```
import { requestTrackingPermissionsAsync } from 'expo-tracking-transparency';

//Request tracking info
  export async function request() {
    try {
      const { status } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        Analytics.record('ResquestGranted')
      }
      else{
        Analytics.record('ResquestDenied')
      }
    } catch (err) { console.log('error requestTrackingPermissionsAsync', JSON.stringify(err))}
  }
```

ATT permission request appear on iOS 16 and below, but not in iOS 16.1

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/71364832/1384679